# React Native - Firebase Database causes app to refresh on value change

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Is it a normal behavior for Firebase to auto-refresh my app when data is modified in the database? Because I have not implemented any refreshing and all of a sudden I go back to my main window if I change a value from the database.

I read that `setState` may cause the refreshing. So I intentionally added the following lines:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this._ismounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this._ismounted = false;
  }
```

Every time I want to call setState I check `if(this._ismounted)`, still somehow my app refreshes entirely.

I am quite inexperienced with Firebase and would definitely be happy to receive any kind of explanation or feedback regarding this matter.

This is how I am using firebase:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._ismounted = true;
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase
      .database().ref("users/" + userId).on("value", snapshot => {
        if(this._ismounted) {
           this.setState({
           firstName: snapshot.child("firstName").val(),
           lastName: snapshot.child("lastName").val(),
           birthDay: snapshot.child("dateOfBirth").val()
        }
    });}
```

Comment: Now that depends on the code you have written, can you please share code snippet of how you are reading data from firebase in your app?

Comment: Where do you modify your data? How does your component look like?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using firebase query. If you are using `on` event. It will refresh every time the data in firebase changes.

Comment: I have added the code I am using to the description of my problem above. I am actually using `.on` to retrieve the data from firebase. Might this be the reason that my whole panel restarts? I only wish to retrieve the information one single time and do not wish to refresh until the user manually presses the refresh button. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to answer this without having a look at your code is to make you understand the basics of firebase.

Firebase has various types of listener a detailed description about it can be found in their official documentation over
[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write). If you are using the 'on' listener with the 'value' event

```
database.child('/childNode').on('value', (snapshot) =>{this.setState(Object) })
```

The above piece of code will always change the data in your state which you are calling 'auto-refresh'. This will keep on changing data in your state until you don't detach the listener

On the other hand if you do

```
database.child('/childNode').once('value').then( (snapshot)=> { this.setState(Object)}).catch( err => console.log(err) )
```

This type of listener will only fetch you data once and even if your data in firebase changes it won't update the data in your state again.

Depending upon your requirements you should choose a suitable listener. Using a on value listener on a root node will fetch you everything in your database even if one small data is changed in some child node and whereas using once listener will fetch you stale data if you want to continuously keep the data updated.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for more explanation.

Edit:

In reference to the explanation above and your code ( assuming you only want to fetch data once and not update it again when it is changed in the database) you could use the once listener.

```
firebase.database().ref("users/" + userId).once("value").then( (snapshot) => {
           this.setState({
           firstName: snapshot.child("firstName").val(),
           lastName: snapshot.child("lastName").val(),
           birthDay: snapshot.child("dateOfBirth").val(),
         });
  }
```

Comment: Indeed the problem was using `.on`. After changing it to `.once` everything started working as supposed to. Thank you for providing me insight on how firebase works. If I were to manually refresh my panel, should I just call forceUpdate on the panel? I mean is this a good practice or should I do it in another way?

Comment: What do you mean by manually refreshing data? Do you mean through the app for eg the user will perform some gesture and the data should be updated?
If so the same piece of code could be used with the gesture.
The code will pull all the data from firebase on performing the gesture and then you can simply setState.

Comment: Yes, if the user decides to swipe down in order to refresh the information from the current panel. What should the function that is called be? Should it just call the .once method above again?

Comment: Yes. You can call the same .once method again when the user swipes down

Comment: Thank you, sir! You have been really helpful. I hope you have a nice day.